# If someone lost a ketubah, are they obligated to replace it

Tags: halacha, marriage, ketubah, lost-and-found, even-haezer

According to Halacha, if a Jewish married couple has a Ketubah and they lost it, are they obligated to have it replaced with another Ketubah or no? Is it considered like an obligation to have throughout marriage, or only when you first get married?

Comment: They cannot live together until they replace it with a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shulchan Aruch in אבן העזר ס׳ סו ס׳ג writes:
אם כתב לה כתובה ונאבדה או שמחלה לו…צריך לכתוב אחרת בעיקר הכתובה שאסור לאדם לשהות עם אשתו שעה אחת בלא כתובה:

If a person writes a Kesuba for her and then it gets lost… he must write for her a new one for the main monies of the Kesuba for it is forbidden to remain with his wife for even one hour without a Kesuba.

Comment: See there for more details why this may not apply anymore, so be sure to CYLOR if this happens to you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a new one will need to be written.

How quickly it must be done, As @ASL quoted the Shulchan Aruch, Sefardim have more stringent laws in regards to a truly lost Kesubah, as not only living together is prohibited, Yichud (remaining together in a closed room) is prohibited as well. For one of Ashkenazi descent, Yichud is permitted, but living together is prohibited. If the Witnesses on the Kesubah are still around and still remember the wedding then it may help with both Yichud and living together, until a new Kesubah is able to be written.

Definitely a question for your LOR.

(See Chelkas Mechokek and Beis Shmuel on the Shulchan Aruch quoted by @ASL)